# CakePHP App not working on web server

Tags: cakephp, model

I tried to upload my app to webserver to check it's performance, but unfortunately I got weird error:

> Error:  Database table news for model
>   News was not found.

The Most funny things are:
- In Model file I got var $useTable = 'other table name';
- This table exist, connection with DB too!
- on my local server everythings works great...

Any suggestions? Yes, I cleared the cache.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check model file name, capitalization matters on some server but not all. if it cant find the model file, then it doesnt know $userTable. just guessing

Comment: It's everything correct. Just $userTable seems to be not visible for CakePHP. Damn, have no idea what could be wrong.